# Doesn't Internet explorer support $.ajax method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am getting a problem when I am trying to invoke the `$.ajax()` method in Internet Explorer.

My code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://my_server/resource.php",
    success: my_function
});
```

When I am testing this in any browser I get the proper answer, but if I'm using Internet Explorer, it only takes the url: `http://my_server/` where the `resource.php` part is left out and the response is empty.

Any suggestions?  Should I send the `resource.php` part in the data field?

Comment: `success: function` is wrong unless in your original code you have correct function handler eg `success: function(data){....}`

Comment: There must be something else wrong here. This is certainly supported across browsers, including IE.

Comment: What version of jQuery and IE are you using? How to you know that the request is only targeting http://my_server are you using fiddler?

Comment: Your code looks fine. `$.ajax` works just fine in Internet Explorer.

Comment: 'function' is a method that I have defined in my code, this is not the problem, it works perfectly with any other browser, It is only using IE.

Comment: @user1089964 `function` is a reserved keyword to declare a function, using it as the name of a function strikes me as very wrong. Have you tried renaming your function to something other than 'function' to see if, in fact, that **is** the problem?

Comment: I know that the request is only targeting http://my_server/ because I used wireshark to find it out.

Comment: Just because you have something that works in one browser and not another does not mean the browser has a bug.  It likely means the opposite, using non-standard code causes inconsistent cross-browser results.  `.ajax()` most certainly works in IE or you'd have tens of millions of broken websites.  Now read these comments again...

Comment: Thanks. Right now I realized that It neither works in Opera. I guess It should have something to do with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.. http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it DOES work

If that's your current code, then there is incorrect definition of function . You have to use

```
success: function() { 
//.....
}
```

Comment: @Sparky672, Ooops, but Thanks. Daniel: Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the page that is using this JavaScript being served by `http://my_server`?

Most modern browsers support Cross Origin Resource Sharing, but IE has yet to fully implement it in any released version, which will likely mean that you either get a HEAD request sent to the script to check for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, or a cross domain violation.

http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS

http://enable-cors.org/

If your page is being served from `http://my_server`, make sure that the syntax is correct (currently you are missing the rest of the success handler: `success: function() {}`. If `function` is the name of your function, it is a reserved word so should be replaced with another variable name.

Comment: The page that is using it is served by http://my_server:another_port/ 

There are two different servers.. one serving the page and another on answering that kind of requests.. Do you think that is the problem? 

I will read about this "cross domain violation". Thanks.

Comment: I think It has something to do with what you mean, It is not supported  in Opera either.. as that table shows..

Comment: That would cause you a problem yes... cross domain policy requires that the protocol, host and port are all the same. If you have apache running, it may be worth looking into ProxyPass to route requests for some URL through to the other server so all requests can be on the same domain http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you are not including jquery at the right moment.

Comment: The fact that it's not a problem in other browsers suggests it's more than simply a problem with scripts being included.

Answer (score 0):

have you referred all JQuery JS Files Properly?